# Symfony Forms CollectionType, index by ID

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I'm working on a Symfony 4 Form with embedded types for a REST API. The form:

```
class OffertaType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('pulsanti_social_attivi', CheckboxType::class, [ ])
            ->add('immagini', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => OffertaImmagineType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'prototype' => 'immagini'
            ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            [
                'data_class'         => Offerta::class,
                'allow_extra_fields' => true,
                'csrf_protection'    => false,
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

The collection contains 2 objects

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=1"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=2"
    }
]
```

All "works", if I post some data a new object is created and if I update an object the DB is updated. The strange thing is the update/delete of row seem based on the object position in the collection and not on its ID. If I delete the first object the result should be

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=2"
    }
]
```

but its

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=2"
    }
]
```

Symfony see only 1 object, so delete the second one and update the first one "url" field.

How can I "index" the collection by the objects' ID and not by their position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is impossible in fact. Just accept that Symfony Collections are index-based and deal with it. You can move along with one of the possible solutions.

For example, you can create separate delete button for collection items, then set

```
'delete_empty' => false,
'allow_delete' => false,
```

to use your form only for adding new entries.

Or you can set `delete_empty` and `allow_delete` to true, but in this case you should set empty elements for collection position you want actually remove.

Another option is to create a unique handler for your form according to your specific requirements, but I can't give you a particular example because I don't know what do you need at the moment.

Comment: Oh, ok! Thank you for your answer. My problem is not limited to deleting, but also updating items with sortable orders and suchs, the delete was only an example. Can you point me in the right direction for some of the "possible solutions"? I already googled for days but all I found are basic level tutorial whitch totally skip the problem.

Comment: well, I don't think I can suggest the most efficient solution for you, because I simply have no idea what are the requirements for your API, how you gonna use it and for what purposes. it is up to you. Just keep in mind that Symfony will compare every new collection, submitted through the form, with the one stored in DB depending on index. If some element of collection is missing - it will delete it from DB, if some element looks different - it will update an element in DB, even `id` will be rewrited. Do all required data preparation on the other side, from where you sending a request

Comment: Ok, thanks. As I see it symfony forms is not a tool I can use in my scenario (or any write enabled API scenario) as I cant expect the users to enforce these strange constraints.

Comment: If you think Form Collection is not an option for you, then probably you should consider separate end-points for adding, updating and deleting `OffertaImmagine`, this would add some more complexity to your API, because now you have one end-point for `Offerta` and three more for `OffertaImmagine`, but it would be much easier to understand how to deal with this particular entity

Answer (score 2):

There's an opened ticket in Symfony's repository to add a feature to `CollectionType` to index the items on a custom field: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/7828 That would take care of the problem you have but that ticket is still open and hasn't moved forward.

However, further down the thread, people found a work-around by manually changing the `ArrayCollection` of entities to index it using ids, like so:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $entity = $builder->getData();

    // Reindex collection using id
    $indexedCollection = new ArrayCollection();
    foreach ($entity->getCollectionField() as $collectionItem) {
        $indexedCollection->set($collectionItem->getId(), $collectionItem);
    }

    $builder
        ->add('collectionField', CollectionType::class, [
            'data' => $indexedCollection,
        ])
    ;
}
```

(copied from Seb33300's answer https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/7828#issuecomment-579608260).

Then you can send back this JSON:

```
{
    "immagini": {
        "2": {"url": "http://new-url.com"}
    }
}
```

And it will get mapped to the entity with id 2 in the Collection.

Comment: Thanks, its very interesting. Next time I need something like that I will try it!

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks! I use this in combination with GUID's

Answer (score 0):

@Link14 answer led me to dig in doctrine documentation, if not possible to get structure like that for DB data directly.

You can do so by using "indexBy" option

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.13/tutorials/working-with-indexed-associations.html

```
    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Stock", mappedBy="market", indexBy="id")
     * @var Stock[]
     */
    private $stocks;
```